# How to call reflection methods in freemarker template?

Tags: java, reflection, code-generation, freemarker

We can iterate over class fields, annotations with some code like this in java:

```
Class<?> clazz;
for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
    for(Annotation annotation : field.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
        for(Method method : annotation.annotationType().getMethods()) {
            if(method.getName().equals("nullable")) {
                try {
                    // note this line
                    System.out.println(method.invoke(annotation, (Object[])null) );
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Ex");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

above codes want to check that if one of annotations of fields have `nullable` method, log it's value. assume this field  some class:

```
public class someClass {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long number;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", nullable = true)
    private Entity entity;
}
```

That above code for this class logs `false`, then `true` as a value of `nullable` attribute in field annotations. Now i want to iterate over class fields and annotations in freemarker template, but the problem is that i cant call `method.invoke(annotation, (Object[])null)`.

```
<#list fields as field>
    <#list field.annotations as annotation>
        <#if annotation??>
            <#if annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName() == "Column" || annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName() == "JoinColumn">
                <#list annotation.annotationType().getMethods() as annotationMethod>
                    <#attempt>
                        <#if annotationMethod.getName() == "nullable">
                            // this line get error 
                            ${annotationMethod.invoke(annotation, (Object[])null)}
                        </#if>
                        <#recover>
                    </#attempt>
                </#list>
                <#break>
            </#if>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#list>
```

Is there another way to achieve this goal in freemarker template?
I want to use these code for code generator.

**UDPATE**

this is the exception that i gave:

```
Syntax error in template "entity-detail.ftl" in line 32, column 111:
Encountered "]", but was expecting one of:
    <STRING_LITERAL>
    <RAW_STRING>
    "false"
    "true"
    <INTEGER>
    <DECIMAL>
    "."
    "+"
    "-"
    "!"
    "["
    "("
    "{"
    <ID>
freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "entity-detail.ftl" in line 32, column 111:
Encountered "]", but was expecting one of:
    <STRING_LITERAL>
    <RAW_STRING>
    "false"
    "true"
    <INTEGER>
    <DECIMAL>
    "."
    "+"
    "-"
    "!"
    "["
    "("
    "{"
    <ID>
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:5749)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:5608)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.UnaryExpression(FMParser.java:658)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MultiplicativeExpression(FMParser.java:768)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AdditiveExpression(FMParser.java:720)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RangeExpression(FMParser.java:900)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RelationalExpression(FMParser.java:848)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.EqualityExpression(FMParser.java:811)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AndExpression(FMParser.java:967)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OrExpression(FMParser.java:989)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Expression(FMParser.java:548)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.DynamicKey(FMParser.java:1341)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AddSubExpression(FMParser.java:1107)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.PrimaryExpression(FMParser.java:607)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.UnaryExpression(FMParser.java:653)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MultiplicativeExpression(FMParser.java:768)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AdditiveExpression(FMParser.java:720)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RangeExpression(FMParser.java:900)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RelationalExpression(FMParser.java:848)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.EqualityExpression(FMParser.java:811)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AndExpression(FMParser.java:967)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OrExpression(FMParser.java:989)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Expression(FMParser.java:548)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Parenthesis(FMParser.java:616)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.PrimaryExpression(FMParser.java:588)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.UnaryExpression(FMParser.java:653)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MultiplicativeExpression(FMParser.java:768)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AdditiveExpression(FMParser.java:720)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RangeExpression(FMParser.java:900)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RelationalExpression(FMParser.java:848)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.EqualityExpression(FMParser.java:811)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AndExpression(FMParser.java:967)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OrExpression(FMParser.java:989)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Expression(FMParser.java:548)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.PositionalArgs(FMParser.java:2985)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MethodArgs(FMParser.java:1357)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AddSubExpression(FMParser.java:1111)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.PrimaryExpression(FMParser.java:607)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.UnaryExpression(FMParser.java:653)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MultiplicativeExpression(FMParser.java:768)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AdditiveExpression(FMParser.java:720)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RangeExpression(FMParser.java:900)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.RelationalExpression(FMParser.java:848)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.EqualityExpression(FMParser.java:811)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.AndExpression(FMParser.java:967)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OrExpression(FMParser.java:989)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Expression(FMParser.java:548)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.StringOutput(FMParser.java:1522)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3721)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.If(FMParser.java:1625)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3384)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Attempt(FMParser.java:1671)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3511)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.List(FMParser.java:1746)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3388)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.If(FMParser.java:1625)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3384)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.If(FMParser.java:1625)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3384)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.List(FMParser.java:1746)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3388)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Attempt(FMParser.java:1671)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3511)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.List(FMParser.java:1746)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3388)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:3772)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Root(FMParser.java:4411)
    at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:252)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:549)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplateInternal(TemplateCache.java:439)
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:292)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2654)
    at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2503)
    at com.vira.framework.common.generator.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.java:70)
    at com.vira.framework.common.generator.CodeGeneratorTest.main(CodeGeneratorTest.java:7)
```

Comment: Why you can't call it exactly? What's the error message?

Comment: dear @ddekany please check my update

Comment: Ah... there's no casting nor type names in the template language. (Nor `null`... though if nothing defined a variable called like that, it will work in this case.) Anyway, that's a varargs there, so how about `annotationMethod.invoke(annotation)`?

Comment: no, `annotationMethod.invoke(annotation)` cannot be call, because as you see in the java code, it have to parameter as input

Comment: You also want to add a `!` after the method call, or else FreeMarker will complain if it return `null`. Like `${method.invoke(annotation)!}`.

Comment: But it's a varargs parameter, so it can be omitted. See in the API: `invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`.

Comment: `${annotationMethod.invoke(annotation)!}` didn't worked :(

Comment: What was the error message? Please understand, error messages matter. "Didn't worked" doesn't help.

Comment: Dear @ddekany, i know but i'm too tired now, i put error here few hours later

Answer (score 0):

If you just get "nullable" value from your annotation.You don't need this code

```
       <#list annotation.annotationType().getMethods() as annotationMethod>
                <#attempt>
                    <#if annotationMethod.getName() == "nullable">
                        // this line get error 
                        ${annotationMethod.invoke(annotation, (Object[])null)}
                    </#if>
                    <#recover>
                </#attempt>
            </#list>
```

just write this!!

```
${annotation.nullable()}
```

Comment: ha ha, be hamin khial bash :D, it didn't worked for me, i resolved the problem with another way

Comment: I used this code & it's work fine.Could you explain what this code didn't work for you??